# MongoDB - Meteor : Update, add and delete an element from an array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to select a specific element in an nested array in a hash like so.

```
post:{
      _id,
      comments:[{
          comment_id:post.comments.length + 1,
          comment: "hello world",
          user_id:Meteor.userId()}]
}
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to add/edit/delete the nested comment by comment_id but I am having trouble trying to select the element I need in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have `comments` in your `post` object you should only have a `comments` array like this:

```
Posts {
   _id: String;
   comments: [];
}
```

And to delete a comment by his id :

```
Posts.update({_id: postId, "comments.comment_id" : "commentIdToDelete"}, 
{ $pull:{"comments": {"comment_id": "commentIdToDelete"}}})
```

To update a comment by his id :

```
Posts.update({_id: postId, "comments.comment_id" : "commentIdToUpdate"}, 
{ $set:{"comments.$.comment": "A new comment"}})
```

**UPDATE**

In order to add a comment in the `comments` array we have to initialiaze the `post` document (if it's not already done):

```
  Posts.insert({
      comments: []
  });
```

Now we have to retrieve the `comments` array size of the `post` to update:

```
let lengthComments = Posts.findOne({_id: postIdToUpdate}).comments.length;
```

And finally we can add a comment in the `comments` array:

```
Posts.update({_id: postIdToUpdate}, {
    $push: {
        "comments": {
             "comment_id": lengthComments + 1,
             "comment": "My comment",
             "user_id": Meteor.userId(),
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How would I go about selecting a specific post object and modifying that specific comments array? As I have it setup right now, I have setup the comment_id to start off at 1 and increase by 1 per post.

Comment: In your setup there is something I don't understand: the `comments` it's an array or it's an object in an array ?

Comment: Comments is an array. I would like to set it up so that the comments is an array of comment hashes which contain user_id, comment, and comment_id which is simply defined as 1 + the length of the array per post.